# How to move from Fedora 3 to Centos 6

Tags: centos6

I am new to Linux but would like to configure a server with Centos 6 to replace a current one running old Fedora Linux Release 3

Comment: 1. Backup data and config.
2. Setup new server.
3. Restore data and config.
4. Replace servers.
What is your exact question?

Comment: Way too old to update. Better format and backup the important config files.

Comment: I have an existing Server with Fedora 3. I need to setup a new server to replace this one. I needed help as to what I need to do to ensure I dont lose services and configurations on the changeover

Comment: Be advice that if you have there some websites php apps this apps will have problems running on centos 6 with newest php versions... If you have there apps running on php 4 they may not work properly on php 5 and you will have to compile php 4 for them or rewrite all aps to php5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fedora 3 is *ancient*. You are basically going to need to start from scratch, but might be able to copy at least parts of the config files when configuring the new server (in most cases, I would not recommend to just copy the files, at least not without a good review of what might have changed in newer versions of a service).

Comment: Wrong. Fedora 3 isn't ancient, it is prehistoric. So much has changed in the meantime that this is more of a "install from scratch" proposition.

Answer (score -1):

```
1st step what all services your running on Fedora 3.
2nd step example :- if you running vsftpd (vsftpd.conf & /etc/vsftpd/user_list)
3rd step install Cent OS 6 with vsftpd .
4th Step ssh to both server config all required setting in new server.
```

copy and paste may be or may not work bcoz of new version of vsftpd.